# GCM optimisation using $M_0$ and $R$ tables - Calculation of $R$

Tags: encryption, gcm, aes-gcm

I'm implementing GCM in C as a way to learn about it. In the paper titled as [The Galois/Counter Mode of Operation (GCM)](http://luca-giuzzi.unibs.it/corsi/Support/papers-cryptography/gcm-spec.pdf) by McGrew and Viega on chapter 4.1, page 11, 12, they talk about the optimisation of GCM via usage of the tables $M_0$ and $R$. What I'm not understanding is how to calculate the table $R$, which shall contain the products of $x \cdot P^{128}$.

The Paper doesn't go more in depth about it, can some of you help me with my understanding of it?

Comment: I'm sorry that I forgot that, its chapter 4.1, the short text about $R$ is in the last paragraph on page 11 and at the start of page 12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P$, defined on p. 8, is a representation of a primitive element in $\operatorname{GF}(2^{128})$; specifically, if we represent the field by $\operatorname{GF}(2)[t]/(f)$ where $f = t^{128} + t^7 + t^2 + t + 1$, $P$ represents the polynomial $t$, *i.e.* $0 + t + 0 t^2 + 0 t^3 + \cdots + 0 t^{127}$.

If $x$ is a byte, represented as some polynomial in $\operatorname{GF}(2)[t]$, then there are only 256 possible values of $x$.  The table $x\cdot P^{128}$ maps each possible byte to the corresponding polynomial $x\cdot t^{128}$ reduced modulo $f$.

Answer (score 0):

I've used Algorithm 3 of the paper for this purpose.

$M[128] ← e1||0^{120} $ instead of H

$P ← 04||0^{120} $ which is 2 with reverse bits